# Prove or disprove: $\forall A,B\;\;A\cup B=A \implies B=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I think the statement is false because if $A=B=\lbrace a\rbrace $ then $ A\cup B=A$ but $B\ne \emptyset$.

It's false, isn't it? I'm a rookie.

Comment: Yes, completely false. $A\cup B= A$ only implies that $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Perhaps you mistyped the question and the quantification should be just "for all $A$".